# rocket.rs CORS No matching routes for OPTIONS >> No 404 catcher registered. Using Rocket default. >> Response succeeded

Tags: rust, cors, rust-rocket

rocket.rs is failing to setup cors properly..
how can i make this work

using rocket.rs 0.5-rc.3

```rust
pub struct CORS;

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl Fairing for CORS {
    fn info(&self) -> Info {
        Info {
            name: "Add CORS headers to responses",
            kind: Kind::Response
        }
    }

    async fn on_response<'r>(&self, _request: &'r Request<'_>, response: &mut Response<'r>) {
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PATCH, OPTIONS"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"));
    }
}
```

```rust
fn main(){

let _rocket = rocket::build()
        .manage(state).attach(CORS)
        ...
}
```

Keep getting the same error

```
OPTIONS /some/route:
No matching routes for OPTIONS /some/route.
No 404 catcher registered. Using Rocket default.
Response succeeded.
```